# How do you capture and store a MeshEntry/P2P Endpoint from a CustomPeerResolverService?

Tags: c#, wcf, p2p, servicehost, wcf-endpoint

Is it possible to capture and store a MeshEntry much in the same way as you can capture a client callback channel via OperationContext.Current.GetCallbackChannel<>?

I can see the MeshEntrys listed in the CustomPeerResolverService but im not sure if its possible for a peer to identify and target a specific peer. I would still like the server to keep a callback channel to each client but is it possible store the MeshEntry or something similar as a property in my client class and leave the CallbackChannel deserialised. Im wanting a peer to contact another peer via this channel.

Thanks

Comment: I have found a good resource here for anyone looking. http://blogs.msdn.com/b/peerchan/archive/2007/06/20/extending-the-defaultpeercustomresolver.aspx

Comment: also http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms733062.aspx has some good info on this too

Comment: I also found that a CustomPeerResolverService is probably not the best for one on one p2p connection but rather use system.net.PeertoPeer and resolve ur endpoints with Pnrp storing the uri + ports on the wcf instance along with the OperationContext and any other client details. If this pnrp fails then you can try upnp using a decent api. or perhaps a udp/tcp hole punch. finally i could refer back to relaying the information over the server(last resort).

Comment: I wonder also if another client in the mesh can filter and find a peer if it has its PeerNode detail.. ie PeerNode myPeerNode = ((IChatChannel)channela).GetProperty<PeerNode>();